# Django requests with ajax

Tags: ajax, django

I working on a simple mvc application where I have to submit forms with ajax. Then I create a class with purpose to manage all requests from specific module

```
class Produto(View):
    template_name = 'produto/index.html'

    def get(self, request):
        context = {
            'modulos': CELLO_APPS,
            'modulo': 'Produtos'
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request):

        if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
            return JsonResponse({'FOO': 'BAR'})
        else:
            raise Http404
```

this looks pretty logical to me, but it doesn't work and raise an error

> missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

the only way I could solve this problem was setting post method as static

```
class Produto(View):
    template_name = 'produto/index.html'

    def get(self, request):
        context = {
            'modulos': CELLO_APPS,
            'modulo': 'Produtos'
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

def post(request):

    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        return JsonResponse({'FOO': 'BAR'})
    else:
        raise Http404
```

So I have two doubts:

1- How can I create a single class with many functions accessible by ajax?

2- Would be this the best or recommended way to manage those views? (Considering this application can grow a lot in the future)

Edit.

Here follows my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^inserir', Produto.inserir, name='produto_inserir'),
    url(r'^$', Produto.as_view(), name='cliente'),
]
```

Comment: Can you show your urls.py file? Are you using `Produto.as_view()`. BTW, have you looked at django rest framework? That's how most people implement an API, which is what you need.

Comment: Is this django rest framework an extension to django to manage requests?

Comment: What is `Produto.inserir`? in your urls? With class based views, always use `as_view()` method. If you try to call a instance method without an instance, the `self` argument will not be inserted.

Comment: It's the most popular package for supporting a Rest API, which is how must people support Ajax today. It makes what you want to do very easy: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: Thank you all, now I can see my mistake, I will look for this api right now